# How to efficiently replace elements in an unordered_set while iterating over it?

Tags: c++, iterator, replace, unordered-set

Suppose you have an

```
std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<A>> as;
// (there is an std::hash<std::shared_ptr<A>> specialisation)
```

and you want to replace some of its elements while iterating over it:

```
for (auto it = as.begin(); it != as.end(); ++it) {
  if ((*it)->condition()) {
    as.erase(it);
    as.insert(std::make_shared<A>(**it));
  }
}
```

This could **invalidate** the iterator at `erase` and `insert` (if rehashing takes place), so this loop will exhibit undefined behaviour and will most likely crash horribly.

The one solution I can think of is using two separate `vector`s to buffer the `insert` and `erase` operations and later use the overloads that take iterator pairs for erasing and inserting (this is presumably more rehashing-friendly).

Even if I use the buffer approach, this still seems bloated code and could result in two rehashes that might possibly both be unnecessary.

So, is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just thought of a possible approach (just after asking) but maybe there are even better ones.

Copying everything to a vector and then rebuilding the set from the vector should be faster:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr> buffer;
buffer.reserve(as.size());
for (auto it = as.begin(); it != as.end(); ++it) {
  if ((*it)->condition()) {
    buffer.push_back(std::make_shared<A>(**it));
  } else {
    buffer.push_back(*it);
  }
}
as = std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<A>>(buffer.begin(),buffer.end());
```

Comment: Do not forget the `assign` method, which effectively resets a container to a new content.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: What's the advantage over `operator=`?

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I cannot find anything about `unordered_set::assign`. Are you sure there is such a method?

Comment: Interestingly: there seems to be none. There is one for `vector` or `list`, but it seems associative containers did not get one. Normally the advantage is that you do not need to construct a temporary storage (like you do here). You can always emulate it by using `as.clear(); as.insert(buffer.begin(), buffer.end());` though assign (in lists and such) is potentially optimized better by reusing existing storage rather than deallocating and then reallocating the nodes one at a time.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Well, constructing a new object cannot be worse that `insert`ing, and the `operator=` is probably constant-time, as it swaps the contents out of the the temporary. But I'm never sure when I have to use `std::move` to allow this behaviour.

Comment: Actually, constructing a new object *can* be worse that inserting. Think of a `vector` (since it's simple). If you take a vector of 5 elements, and apply `assign` with 3 elements, it just overwrites the first 3 elements and sets the size. If you build a new vector first (to use `operator=`), then you will need to dynamically allocate memory for this new vector.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: True. I suppose the question is whether `clear` actually frees the memory or not. And if the memory will turn out to be sufficiently large.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `as.erase(it)` the iterator `it` become invalidated. Inserting into an unordered associative containers invalidates all iterators. Thus, the insertion needs to be separated from the iterator. Avoiding the insertions is also necessary to avoid processing the newly inserted objects:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> replaced;
for (auto it = as.begin(); it != as.end(); ) {
    if ((*it)->condition()) {
        replaced.push_back(std::make_shared<A>(**it));
        as.erase(it++);
    }
    else {
        ++it;
    }
}
std::copy(replaced.begin(), replaced.end(), std::inserter(as, as.begin());
```

Comment: No, I don't want to do that, because in **unordered** sets, even `insert` *invalidates all iterators*, as I pointed out in the question text. Also `erase` invalidates **all** iterators, not just the one currently erased!

Comment: According to 23.2.5 [unord.req] paragraph 13 it does not invalidate iterators others than those affected by the erase: "... The erase members shall invalidate only iterators and references to
the erased elements." However, this means that the inserting and erasing in the same loop does not work (and I'll remove this from my response).

Comment: Now, that I think of it. `std::inserter` probably causes several rehashes along the way, so I don't see the improvement over the solution that causes only two rehashes tops (see OP).

Comment: Inserting the elements directly back may cause the newly inserted elements being iterated over again: the new element may end up after the current iterator position. The number of potential rehashes doesn't change with inserting them back in afterwards: one potential rehash per inserted object.

Comment: No, look at the second and third paragraph after the code block in the OP. The code block itself is just my intention.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put this as a comment on @bitmask's answer. Why not just use the vector for the replaced elements?

```
std::vector<decltype(as)::value_type> buffer;
buffer.reserve(as.size());
for (auto it = as.begin(); it != as.end(); )
{
  if ((*it)->condition())
  {
    buffer.push_back(*it);
    it = as.erase(it);
  }
  else
  {
    ++it;
  }
}
as.insert(buffer.begin(),buffer.end());
```

And, if `*it` is already a `shared_ptr<A>`, I fail to see a reason to `make_shared()` again. Just assign and let the copy constructor/assignment operators work their magic.

Answer (score -1):

In your case you can just swap in my opinion:

```
for(auto iter = as.begin(); iter != as.end(); ++iter)
{
    if(/*Check deletion condition here*/)
    {
        auto newItem = std::make_shared<A>(/*...*/);
        swap(*iter, newItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Holy Zombie! That will undefine-murder the map. Do not ever change the hash value of elements. Ever!

Comment: But you were copy constructing in your question, that's why I offered swap. That's why I said "In your case". If your are going to change internal state afterwards, it is same as changing the key.

Comment: The hash consists of the pointer value, thus even if I copy construct, it will have the same hash value than the previous pointer. The swapping operation will change the element, without allowing the map to put that element in the right slot; `newItem` would be filed away under the hash of `*iter` which must differ, as `**iter` is an old pointer and `*newItem` was just constructed.